# Packages not installing in Idle shell

Tags: python-idle

I am using python Idle 3.10.0 on a Mac. I am trying to install the Arcade package, but, the Idle shell keep saying:

```
pip install arcade
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

with the I of invalid highlighted in red. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pip doesn't run inside idle, it runs in terminal. This is because idle runs python code, but `pip` is a terminal command. In terminal run `pip install arcade`. If it doesn't work also try `py -m pip install arcade` or if that doesn't work `python3 -m pip install arcade`

After running this in the terminal it should work in idle with `import arcade`

Comment: still not working, it still says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?` with the - of -m highlighted.

Comment: You are still entering the macOS command in IDLE's shell, which *only* runs python statement.  Open the Terminal app.